# My React app hosted on GitHub shows a 404 when changing the URL manually

Tags: reactjs, heroku, github, github-pages

Link to my app(Works best on Firefox, Edge, CSS is wonky on Chrome): https://dsopel94.github.io/school-app/build/

When I try to change to for example URL/build/login in the address bar, I get a 404 not found. My app only has a 404 not found when refreshing. Using the buttons/links that don't trigger a page refresh works fine. Anyone know what the issue might be?

Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/dsopel94/school-app

Answer (score 0):

It should be so.

This is because your branch **gh-pages** does not contain pages https://dsopel94.github.io/school-app/build/login or https://dsopel94.github.io/school-app/build/signup.

If you want your application to work as a full-fledged single page application, visit the project [spa-github-pages](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages). GitHub will return to you the 404.html, then you need to convert the `routerProps.location.search` back into the path and return the `<Redirect to={path} />` (assuming that you are using react-router).

Comment: thanks I'll try that though I do think there's a different way this can be done without refactoring any routes or components. It was working as intended at one point but reverting to all the previous commits doesn't do anything, odd.